# How to connect AWS ec2 Windows instance in Putty?

Tags: ssh, putty, windows-server-2008, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-ec2

I have created a AWS Windows Ec2 instance, I can able to connect to the remote windows machine by using .rdb file, everything works fine.

Now I need to connect a windows server by using putty. Let me know what inbound and outbound rule should I setup.

My main concern is the port number, what port number should I want to use for connecting windows server in putty.

[image: Outbound]

[image: Inbound]

Answer (score 1):

None, because Windows Server 2008 does not come with an SSH server installed.

If you install a third-party SSH server service (e.g. Bitvise), then use the same port number that was configured in that SSH service. The default SSH port is 22 TCP.

Comment: True for "Windows Server 2008". But not for "Windows Server" in general, now that there's Win32 OpenSSH . You may want to mention that specifically. +1